# Google Cloud Platform - SSH/Telnet

Tags: macos, ssh, google-cloud-platform

I am running apps on Compute Engine. I run on a Windows box and use Putty to connect to the CE. This pretty much seems to work fine (leaving aside the problems in the Google doc on this).

I have set up another user who I want to enable for SSH (on a Mac) and have her use FileZilla to push files to the CE.

I am trying it out on my own Mac. I set up 2 firewall rules with 2 different priorities for tcp:22 =

```
myssh Apply to all  IP ranges: 0.0.0.0/0 tcp:22 Allow 1000 default
default-allow-ssh Apply to all IP ranges: 0.0.0.0/0 tcp:22 Allow 65534 default
```

The user has permissions on of the Project of: "Compute Instance Admin(v1)"

On the Mac terminal I do the following:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -f ~/.ssh/userfirstname-ssh-key -C [googleusername.gmail.com]
```

I go to the GCP CE Meta data (logged in as myself) and then copy the contents of the userfirstname-ssh-key.pub to the Metadata/SSH Keys and save.

After GCP gives the ok on the key being added I enter the following in the Mac terminal:

```
ssh -i [userfirstname]-ssh-key [googleusername.gmail.com]@gcp-external-ip
```

Depending on i-don't-know-what, sometimes it says "Permission denied (public key)", "Operation timed out"

I've repeated this a few times and just tried to telnet in to the gcp-external-ip and get "Operation timed out" telnet: Unable to connect to remote host.

At a complete loss. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You could (and should) use the `gcloud` command line tools. Then it is easiest to simple copy the correct gcloud command from the Web Console. There is a little drop-down menu next to 'SSH' for each of your instances.